# Change cell text depending on date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on a sheet to register customer information. The first cell in each row contact a date, for example: **07.07.2020**. To make it GDPR friendly, I need to make a macro that checks if the date is older then 90 days ago, the name and email column should be marked with "########" or just blank. How can I accomplish this?

I have tried adding it as Conditional Formatting like this (but it doesn't do any changes to my sheet:
[Image: [1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHDF9.png) (Look at the last formula)

```
Formula: =$A6<TODAY()-90
```

Comment: Conditional formatting with formula `=A1<today()-90`. Don't forget to set color. (untested)

Comment: You can accomplish this searching on Google or on this site and trying. You ask a question only after you tried, **presenting here your code** and we will help you making it working. We do not offer the free service of writing code...

Comment: @FaneDuru Read again.

Comment: @OverflowStacker I tried that earlier also, added your solution as image, still not working.

Comment: Should I see some code lines and I am missing something? Anyhow, your question is not clear, even if I would start making some code. "the name and email column" is clear only for you. We would need something to be used in code: Ranges, Columns and rows. How big is your range to be processed? More then one million rows, like I can see in your Conditional Formatting formula?

Comment: So, in what column do you have the date to be compared with Today()? In your question you say "the first cell in each row" and in your formula you used "K6". Are name and email columns A:A and B:B? How many rows does your sheet to be processed has? I have now some time and I cannot do anything if I do not understand what is to be done...

Comment: You may win going on my hand. But I am only focused on details necessary to understand what is to be done. You look not understanding this aspect even how, after explaining what is to be supplied here... Can you answer my questions, please? I was asking about the size in order to know if I will use arrays or simple ranges...

Answer (score 0):

So this would go in the requested direction:

```
=$A2<TODAY()-90
```

[image]

It is working for me. You can push the rule to the top to make it the most important. There are arrows to do that besides the new rule button.

EDIT:
You need to be careful where to set `$`. I updated the equation and the picture.

Comment: OP wants the name and email columns to change color.

Comment: @JMP: And do you know that B:C is not the necessary range...? Nobody, except the one asking the question, does know which these columns are. Even if I asked him in clear... The above solution is a generic one, something to be easily extrapolated to his (secret) real range. But, if the range is the one he suggested in his formulas (more then one million rows), it will tremendously slow down Excel...